# Firebase directory not found

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-cli, firebase-tools

I'm trying to set firebase to host my website.
The issue I have now is that Firebase cannot find the directory to process firebase. I got these messages to setup it by following official document.

executed this command:url -sL https://firebase.tools

> | bash
>   -- Checking for existing firebase-tools on PATH... Your machine already has firebase-tools@7.12.1 installed. Nothing to do.

execute this command:npm install -g firebase-tools

> /usr/local/bin/firebase ->
>   /usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/bin/firebase.js

execute this command:firebase login:ci

> bash: /Users/shincat/.npm-packages/bin/firebase: No such file or
>   directory

I guess path for the firebase would be wrong, however I don't know how to change the path.
I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

I could fix this issue with running the code in terminal.

```
alias firebase="`npm config get prefix`/bin/firebase"
```